# Mongodb: How to get records N to M?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Lets say we want to get records 5 to 10 (second last 5 records).

What query should be used in nodejs or mongodb shell ?

I know to get last 5 messages one could try this (in nodejs):

```
db.collection(collection_name).find().limit(5);
```

Comment: are you using mongodb shell? Please mention clearly any language/framework are you using

Comment: if it's mongodb shell, you can do it as `db.collection.find().skip(5).limit(5)`

Comment: @Saleem Edited, I want a query in either mongodb shell or nodejs.

Comment: try solution I posted above. .skip and .limit will be your friends.

Comment: @Saleem Thanks, It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Saleem posted in the comments, you would need to do a [`.skip()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)

```
db.coll.find(queryDoc).skip(x).limit(y)
```

However, to have a predictable order, you should add a [`.sort()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)

```
db.coll.find(queryDoc).sort(sortDoc).skip(x).limit(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Limit cannot return a set results in a range, it's for literally limiting the results to X number.

Assuming you're still using NodeJS,

What you can try, according to [the documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) is to use [`min`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.min/)/[`max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.max/).

> min {Number}, min set index bounds.
>
> max {Number}, max set index bounds.

```
db.collection(user_name).find().min({index:5}).max({index:10});
```